# Read CSV as crosstab/pivot table

Tags: tables, csv

I've got a table that looks like this:

[image: A crosstab of values]

(*Note: This table was generated in winword by my predecessor, so I don't have a MWE of it. My attempts to do so have failed, as it's apparently not so simple to do row-based manipulations on tables.*)

I have full control over the underlying CSV/TSV data, and I'm trying to generate a version of the table in LaTeX that can be updated yearly when the data changes.

I can get something similar with a pivot table in Excel (see below, but I don't know a way to convert this to LaTeX short of putting py scripts in my makefile that generate the tables on-the-fly. Is there a pure LaTeX way of doing this?

[image]

Edit: Here's an MVE of the above table:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr|rrr}
\cmidrule{2-7}
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{2019}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2020}\\
&Applied&Admitted&\%&Applied&Admitted&\%\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
Resident Freshmen      & 1143 &  918 & 80.3\% & 1094 & 1003 & 91.7\%\\
Non-Resident Freshmen  & 1371 & 1048 & 76.4\% & 1223 & 1090 & 89.1\%\\
\textbf{Total Freshmen} & 2514 & 1966 & 78.2\% & 2317 & 2093 & 90.3\%\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
Resident Transfer       & 404 & 358 & 88.6\% & 406 & 354 & 87.2\%\\
Non-Resident Transfer   & 371 & 313 & 84.4\% & 356 & 288 & 80.9\%\\
\textbf{Total Transfer} & 775 & 671 & 86.6\% & 762 & 642 & 84.3\%\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
Grad/PostBacc & 418 & 311 & 74.4\% & 374 & 282 & 75.4\%\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
\textbf{Grand Total} & 3707 & 2948 & 79.5\% & 3453 & 3017 & 87.4\%\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image: The compiled form of the above code]

My CSV data is mutable (since I control the db producing it.) but at the very least I'm thinking I'd need something such as

```
year, decision, residency, class, count
...
2019,admitted,resident,freshmen, 1143
...
2020, applied,, Grad/PostBacc, 374
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does the CSV data look like and how would it be changed when another year is added? I guess, you would add three more columns to the data? Please provide a short snippet showing how the CSV data is structured.

Comment: With a pivot table, the number of columns in the raw data doesn't necessarily correspond to the number of columns in the output. I'd add 10 or so more rows to the raw data corresponding to the given year, and use a tool (pandas, cognos, or excel, generally) to do the crosstabulation for me.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to do it in pure TeX, so here's a toolchain of various programs that does the trick:

```
Directory structure:
/
+-Data
| +-app_admit_fall.csv
+-Templates
| +-app_admit_fall.pytex
+-Generated
| +-app_admit_fall.tex
+-Makefile
+-generate_file.py
+-document.tex
+-document.pdf
```

```
# Makefile
document.pdf: document.tex app_admit_fall.tex
    rm document.pdf
    rubber --pdf document.tex

# Dependent on the ETL, the data, and the formatting. 
app_admit_fall.tex : generate_file.py Data/app_admit_fall.csv Templates/app_admit_fall.pytex
    python3 generate_file.py app_admit_fall
```

Base document:

```tex
% document.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\input{Generated/app_admit_fall.tex}
\end{document}
```

This is a "template" file for python to use on tex files. Do whatever you'd like to generate this. For myself, I'm using the format `@@{n}` since it's almost guaranteed to not be found in "normal" TeX

```tex
% Templates/app_admit_fall.pytex
\begin{tabular}{rrrr|rrr}
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{@@{1}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{@@{10}}\\
    &Applied&Admitted&\%&Applied&Admitted&\%\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    Resident Freshmen      & @@{2} & @@{11}\\
    Non-Resident Freshmen  & @@{3} & @@{12}\\
    \textbf{Total Freshmen} & @@{4} & @@{13}\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    Resident Transfer       & @@{5} & @@{14}\\
    Non-Resident Transfer   & @@{6} & @@{15}\\
    \textbf{Total Transfer} & @@{7} & @@{16}\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    Grad/PostBacc & @@{8} & @@{17}\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    \textbf{Grand Total} & @@{9} & @@{18}\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
\end{tabular}
```

```py
#!python3
#generate_file.py
### Written by Jakob Lovern
### This file contains functions to generate static tables from the .pytex
### templates in /Templates and the data in /Data. It is *NOT* automatic. 
import sys
import pandas as pd

# Fill the applications/admissions table from app_admit_fall.csv
# Very quick n dirty
def app_admit_fall():
    df = pd.read_csv("Data/app_admit_fall.csv")

    count = 1
    replace_strings = dict()
    def comp_string(input):
        applied = sum(input.query("Decision == 'Applied'")["Count"])
        admitted = sum(input.query("Decision == 'Admitted'")["Count"])
        pct = "%.1f"%(100*admitted/applied)
        return f"{applied} & {admitted} & {pct}\%"
    for year in df["Year"].drop_duplicates().sort_values():
        replace_strings[count] = year
        this_year = df.query("Year == @year")
        class_code = this_year.query("Class=='Freshmen'")
        replace_strings[count+1] = comp_string(class_code.query("Residency=='Resident'"))
        replace_strings[count+2] = comp_string(class_code.query("Residency=='Non-Resident'"))
        replace_strings[count+3] = comp_string(class_code)
        class_code = this_year.query("Class=='Transfer'")
        replace_strings[count+4] = comp_string(class_code.query("Residency=='Resident'"))
        replace_strings[count+5] = comp_string(class_code.query("Residency=='Non-Resident'"))
        replace_strings[count+6] = comp_string(class_code)
        replace_strings[count+7] = comp_string(this_year.query("Class=='Grad/Postbacc'"))

        replace_strings[count+8] = comp_string(this_year)
        count += 9
    print(replace_strings)
    with open("Templates/app_admit_fall.pytex","r") as template:
        filedata = template.read()
    for key, value in replace_strings.items():
        filedata = filedata.replace(f'@@{{{key}}}',str(value))
    with open("Generated/app_admit_fall.tex","w+") as generated:
        generated.write(filedata)

# Add more generators for other files here
generators = {
    'app_admit_fall': app_admit_fall,
}

# Using generators allows us to call specific files from Make,
# which means that we can re-generate only changed files. 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)<2:
        exit(1)
    elif sys.argv[1] in generators:
        generators[sys.argv[1]]()
    else:
        exit(1)
```

And, for MVE purposes, here's my CSV (`Data/app_admit_fall.csv`):

```
Year,Decision,Residency,Class,Count
2019,Applied,Resident,Freshmen,1143
2019,Applied,Resident,Transfer,404
2019,Applied,,Grad/Postbacc,418
2019,Applied,Non-Resident,Freshmen,1371
2019,Applied,Non-Resident,Transfer,371
2019,Admitted,Resident,Freshmen,918
2019,Admitted,Resident,Transfer,358
2019,Admitted,,Grad/Postbacc,311
2019,Admitted,Non-Resident,Freshmen,1048
2019,Admitted,Non-Resident,Transfer,313
2020,Applied,Resident,Freshmen,1094
2020,Applied,Resident,Transfer,406
2020,Applied,,Grad/Postbacc,374
2020,Applied,Non-Resident,Freshmen,1223
2020,Applied,Non-Resident,Transfer,356
2020,Admitted,Resident,Freshmen,1003
2020,Admitted,Resident,Transfer,354
2020,Admitted,,Grad/Postbacc,282
2020,Admitted,Non-Resident,Freshmen,1090
2020,Admitted,Non-Resident,Transfer,288
```

---

Comment: It is probably really easiest to pre-format the CSV data with some other software, so that you get rows in the sensse of `applied 2019, admitted 2019, applied 2020, admitted 2020` etc. LaTeX is not the best tool for long/wide conversion of tabular data (which is essentially what you are aiming for).